# Calculating the difference between dates, excluding weekends

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query/SQL query to calculate the number of working days (excluding Sat/Sun) between two dates.

Comment: What's the database? The date/time database functions differ quite a bit between different vendors.

Comment: It is a Microsoft Access 2010

Comment: If you're in MS Access, you might be as well to created a function in VBA rather than a query for this. It can probably be done inline with built in functions, but the result will look ugly at best. If you create a VBA function then you'll be able to hide the ugliness behind a simple function call. You can even call the Excel function "NetworkDays" which is exactly what you want from VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Turning my comment into an answer here ... Open the VBA editor and under `Tools > References` ensure that you've ticked `Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library`. What is in the place of `XX.X` depends on the version of MS Office you are running.

Then add a new module, the name doesn't matter. In there add the following code:

```
Function WeekdaysBetween(fromDate As Date, toDate As Date)

  WeekdaysBetween = Excel.Application.Networkdays(fromDate, toDate)

End Function
```

In your queries you'll now be able to call this function.

Health warning: VBA functions don't run as quickly as "native" functions, so if you've got a lot of data this may prove to be rather slow.